# How do you unlike a merged page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

A year ago I liked page A.1 on Facebook. Today, I want to unlike it. However, A.1 has merged with A.2 and A.2 now loads when I try to visit A.1.

I do not have A.2 liked (this is what displays on A.2 [image: this is what displays on A.2] and A.2 does not link to A.1. I still have A.1 liked on my profile. How do I unlike A.1?

Comment: What it is mean _A.2 does not link to A.1_? When two page get merged it becomes one page. I have added an answer, for more clarity please add a screenshot to show us what actually you are trying to do.

Comment: There is no link on A.2's page that links to A.1. I added a screenshot of A.2. I cannot provide a screenshot of A.1 because A.1 doesn't load any longer. However, A.1 is still liked on my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the answer to my issue. The solution is to not try to find the page that was liked, but to visit your profile likes sub-page and unlike the "dangling reference" from there via the dropdown element ("unlike").

Answer (score 1):

If page A.1 has merged with A.2, (I suppose here page A.2 has kept at merging time), now when you will try to visit page A.1, it will show page is unavailable. And you liked page A.2 by default, because page A.1 has merged with it and you had liked page A.1. To unlike just go to page A.2 and unlike the page.

Comment: I do not have A.2 liked, in other words, A.2 allows me to like it and assumes I have no liked it yet.